# Visual Studio VBScript Combobox Query

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a Simple project that I working on for a inventory data base

I wrote a query where a item is currently in use will not be displayed in the combobox.

Now when I select an available item in the commobox I receive and error message

> there is already am open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first."

How do I go about closing the datareader?

The following below is a sample  of my code

```
Private Sub LOANERComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LOANERComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            Me.TBL_LOANERSTableAdapter.LOANERCOMBOBOXQRY(Me.LOANER_INVENTORYDataSet.TBL_LOANERS)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub TECHLabel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub STATUSCheckBox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles STATUSCheckBox.CheckedChanged
    If STATUSCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        STATUSCheckBox.Enabled = False
    Else
        STATUSCheckBox.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm assuming your dataset unaccessible is the `Me.LOANER_INVENTORYDataSet` command. Can you please post that code for evaluation?

Comment: Hi rich thanks for replying

Comment: there is no code for the LOANER_INVENTORYDataSet.TBL_LOANERS. the way how i coded is by using creating a query in the fillby toolstrip and copying the code to a combobox to display the query results. here is a copy of my query that i created                                                                                                     SELECT [COMPUTER NAME], ID, SERIAL, STATUS FROM TBL_LOANERS WHERE (STATUS = 'UNCHECKED') ORDER BY [COMPUTER NAME]

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
  <xs:annotation>
xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
      <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">

Comment: <ConnectionRefs>
          <DesignConnectionRef Name="LOANERINVENTORYConnectionString (MySettings)" />
        </ConnectionRefs>
        <Connections>
      <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
        <ConnectionRefs>
          <DesignConnectionRef Name="LOANERINVENTORYConnectionString (MySettings)" />
        </ConnectionRefs>
        <Connections>
          <Connection AppSettingsObjectName="MySettings"